# Can't find a leak from the Static Analyzer

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, clang-static-analyzer

I am getting some errors from the Clang Static Analyzer saying that I have a few leaks from the following code. However I am unable to find the leak. Please tell me where the leak is.

```
 Favourites *fav = [[Favourites alloc] initWithNibName:@"Favourites" bundle:nil];
if (viewController == fav) {
    [fav doHud];
    [fav release];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fav won't be released if viewController does not end up == to fav. You are not setting viewController to be equal to fav so it won't release. Move`[fav release]` outside the `if` and you should be fine.

or get rid of the`[fav release]` altogether and just use autorelease like:

`Favourites *fav = [[[Favourites alloc] initWithNibName:@"Favourites" bundle:nil] autorelease];`